# InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list - warning message received across the site

Tags: list, infopath

I am receiving the below error when trying to customise form in list. I could edit the list in InfoPath before but now I am receiving this error. I created a new list in the same site to check if it's working, but I'm receiving the same error across the site. I am able to do it for another site.

> InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing solution here for others dealing with in 2020 - you need to fix a registry key to adjust the Infopath client for multifactor settings:

Set the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL`                                          REG_DWORD to `1`

And set the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity\Version`                                                REG_DWORD to `1`

Documentation for reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/security-and-compliance/enable-modern-authentication

Comment: Adding the `EnableADAL` DWORD with a value of `1` solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below feature is enabled in Site Collection features.

**"SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features"**

Comment: This was active for me but I am still encountering the error in SharePoint Online. This used to work; pretty darn sure nothing has changed on our side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. The issue is resolved . I just rebooted my system and restarted all the applications which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the Datasheet view in SharePoint and try to edit the form in InfoPath, it will also throw this error.

If this is the cause, just switch from "Datasheet View" to "Standard View".